# (A*) Search on Google Maps Android V2

Tags: android, google-maps, search, android-maps-v2, a-star

I'm trying to implement my own routing algorithm on Google Maps for android. The reason I want to do this is because I want to use a heuristic to find a route closest to a pre-defined length (for example I don't want to travel further than 5 miles, fail if impossible).

I have set up google maps and implemented an XML parser that gives me an ArrayList of LatLng objects of which I can plot and put a polyline through. There are a few issues with this though.

1) the line doesn't stick to roads
2) It only provides one route.

I would really like to use raw map data and run search myself. I see from the google directions API i can go via waypoints but I still cannot think how else to approach this. Ideally I could treat the roads as a map and search them that way.

Would really appreciate any input on libraries or pseudo implementations.

thanks

Comment: google does not provide mapping data aside from the Directions API. if you want to get all the underlying map data you can use OpenStreetMaps

Comment: Hey thanks - so open street maps provides facility to get roads as a graph?

Comment: you can download a file for each state that contains all the street points then you loop through the points using the A* algorithm

Comment: Please could you provide a link that outlines how to do this? I'm coming up short.

Comment: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Downloading_data http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing